# cannot use the part (stats of stats.cat3.detail.name) to traverse the element. nested objects and arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm able to do

```
db.getCollection('comps').find({"stats.cat3.detail.name" : "Friendlyness"})`
```

This shows the proper docs the have a name of "Friendlyness" in the detail array.

I wanted to change "Friendlyness" to "friendliness"

I tried :

```
db.getCollection('comps').update(
   {"stats.cat3.detail.name" : "Friendlyness"},
   {$set : {"stats.cat3.detail.name" : "Friendliness"} }
)
```

and got errors like
"          cannot use the part (stats of stats.cat3.detail.name) to traverse the element ({stats: [ { cat3: ...."

I tried putting in position operators "$" all over the update object property. but still get errors.

sample data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58d94c441eb9e52454932db6"),
    "desc" : "Manufacturer of a wide range of consumer electronics products including audio, video, communications, and computer systems.",
    "source" : "alexa",
    "category" : "Consumer Electronics",
    "name" : "comp1.com",
    "__v" : 0,
    "stats" : [ 
        {
            "cat1" : {
                "detail" : [ 
                    {
                        "value" : [ 
                            {
                                "data" : 1,
                                "name" : "quick service"
                            }
                        ],
                        "name" : "Time on hold"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "value" : [ 
                            {
                                "data" : 1,
                                "name" : "some words but strong accent"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "data" : 1,
                                "name" : "EZ to understand"
                            }
                        ],
                        "name" : "Language fluency"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "value" : [ 
                            {
                                "data" : 1,
                                "name" : "Yes"
                            }
                        ],
                        "name" : "Human answered"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "value" : [ 
                            {
                                "data" : 2,
                                "name" : "Like a hot potato"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "data" : 1,
                                "name" : "1 or 2 times"
                            }
                        ],
                        "name" : "Transfered alot"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "value" : [ 
                            {
                                "data" : 3,
                                "name" : "ok time"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "data" : 1,
                                "name" : "quick service"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "data" : 1,
                                "name" : "short time"
                            }
                        ],
                        "name" : "Time on Hold"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "value" : [ 
                            {
                                "data" : 1,
                                "name" : "some word but strong accent"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "data" : 2,
                                "name" : "EZ to understand"
                            }
                        ],
                        "name" : "Language Fluency"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "value" : [ 
                            {
                                "data" : 2,
                                "name" : "Yes"
                            }
                        ],
                        "name" : "Human Answered"
                    }
                ],
                "average" : 81
            },
            "cat2" : {
                "detail" : [ 
                    {
                        "value" : [ 
                            {
                                "data" : 1,
                                "name" : "It was ok"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "data" : 1,
                                "name" : "Not EZ at all"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "data" : 7,
                                "name" : "there were hidden gimicks"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "data" : 2,
                                "name" : "It was OK"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "data" : 1,
                                "name" : "Found Quickly"
                            }
                        ],
                        "name" : "Easy to find desired product"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "value" : [ 
                            {
                                "data" : 1,
                                "name" : "Easy to understand"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "data" : 1,
                                "name" : "Eventually understood"
                            }
                        ],
                        "name" : "Clear information about the product"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "value" : [ 
                            {
                                "data" : 2,
                                "name" : "none"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "data" : 3,
                                "name" : "There was but won't complain"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "data" : 1,
                                "name" : "Very Bad"
                            }
                        ],
                        "name" : "Annoying popups"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "value" : [ 
                            {
                                "data" : 4,
                                "name" : "Eventually Understood"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "data" : 1,
                                "name" : "EZ to understand"
                            }
                        ],
                        "name" : "Clear data about the product"
                    }
                ],
                "average" : 71
            },
            "cat3" : {
                "detail" : [ 
                    {
                        "value" : [ 
                            {
                                "data" : 1,
                                "name" : "Very quick"
                            }
                        ],
                        "name" : "Prompteness"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "value" : [ 
                            {
                                "data" : 3,
                                "name" : "We're cool"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "data" : 4,
                                "name" : "They didn't like me"
                            }
                        ],
                        "name" : "Friendlyness"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "value" : [ 
                            {
                                "data" : 3,
                                "name" : "Very Confusing"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "data" : 2,
                                "name" : "Still a little confused"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "data" : 3,
                                "name" : "Enlightened"
                            }
                        ],
                        "name" : "Knowledge"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "value" : [ 
                            {
                                "data" : 3,
                                "name" : "On hold too many times"
                            }
                        ],
                        "name" : "Promptness"
                    }
                ],
                "average" : 69
            }

        }
    ]


}
```

Comment: You are meant to be using the [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/), but it's not really going to help you because you have nested arrays. MongoDB cannot match multiple positions in multiple arrays. You can only directly notate the indexes at which to update. But really you should not be using nested arrays.

Comment: Are you reading the documentation? You really need to "flatten" this structure. It's not good for usage with MongoDB.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that the positional operator won't work. I wish I didn't have to change the structure. I just wanted to change the value to Friendliness.

Comment: Well it "works" but at one level deep, just as designed. There is a sitting JIRA issue on this but the real reason it is not resolved is because nesting arrays is simply bad design. Instead you should have one array, with attributes to distinguish different things. Therefore each "nesting" is actually an additional "attribute" on the contained data. This works "really well".